# Iterating over cogrouped RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have used a cogroup function and obtain following RDD:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (Iterable[(Int, Long)], Iterable[(Int, Long)]))]
```

Before the map operation joined object would look like this:

```
RDD[(Int, (Iterable[(Int, Long)], Iterable[(Int, Long)]))]

(-2095842000,(CompactBuffer((1504999740,1430096464017), (613904354,1430211912709), (-1514234644,1430288363100), (-276850688,1430330412225)),CompactBuffer((-511732877,1428682217564), (1133633791,1428831320960), (1168566678,1428964645450), (-407341933,1429009306167), (-1996133514,1429016485487), (872888282,1429031501681), (-826902224,1429034491003), (818711584,1429111125268), (-1068875079,1429117498135), (301875333,1429121399450), (-1730846275,1429131773065), (1806256621,1429135583312))))
(352234000,(CompactBuffer((1350763226,1430006650167), (-330160951,1430320010314)),CompactBuffer((2113207721,1428994842593), (-483470471,1429324209560), (1803928603,1429426861915))))
```

Now I want to do the following:

```
val globalBuffer = ListBuffer[Double]()
val joined = data1.cogroup(data2).map(x => {
  val listA = x._2._1.toList
  val listB = x._2._2.toList
  for(tupleB <- listB) {
    val localResults = ListBuffer[Double]()
    val itemToTest = Set(tupleB._1)
    val tempList = ListBuffer[(Int, Double)]()
    for(tupleA <- listA) {
      val tValue = someFunctionReturnDouble(tupleB._2, tupleA._2)
      val i = (tupleA._1, tValue)
      tempList += i
    }
    val sortList = tempList.sortWith(_._2 > _._2).slice(0,20).map(i => i._1)
    val intersect = sortList.toSet.intersect(itemToTest)
    if (intersect.size > 0)
      localResults += 1.0
    else localResults += 0.0
    val normalized = sum(localResults.toList)/localResults.size
    globalBuffer += normalized
  }
})

//method sum
def sum(xs: List[Double]): Double = {//do the sum}
```

At the end of this I was expecting joined to be a list with double values. But when I looked at it it was unit. Also I will this is not the Scala way of doing it. How do I obtain `globalBuffer` as the final result.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if I understood your code correctly, it could benefit from these improvements:

```
val joined = data1.cogroup(data2).map(x => {
  val listA = x._2._1.toList
  val listB = x._2._2.toList
  val localResults = listB.map { 
    case (intBValue, longBValue) =>
    val itemToTest = intBValue // it's always one element
    val tempList = listA.map {
       case (intAValue, longAValue) =>
       (intAValue, someFunctionReturnDouble(longBvalue, longAValue))
    }
    val sortList = tempList.sortWith(-_._2).slice(0,20).map(i => i._1)
    if (sortList.toSet.contains(itemToTest)) { 1.0 } else {0.0}
// no real need to convert to a set for 20 elements, by the way
  }
  sum(localResults)/localResults.size
})
```

Comment: Also, there's no need to create the list `localResult` -- just keeping track of counts (two counters) is sufficient.

Comment: @Ashalynd `map` operator is not available at `sortList.toSet.contains(itemToTest)`

Comment: @JasonLenderman: can you demonstrate how would it work? I am curious.

Comment: is it ok that `val joined: RDD[Unit]` at the end for each key there should be a value and that value comes from `sum(localResults)/localResults.size`

Comment: @Ashalynd, please see my answer.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, could you please clarify what you mean in your previous comment. Do you mean you want some sort of running proportion as you're "looping" over `listB`? Please clarify further.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis yes, it's valid in Scala: the result of the last instruction in the function body becomes the value returned by that function. It will be RDD[Double], you'd have to convert it into a list if you need.

Comment: @JasonLenderman yes its like a running proportion. So the idea is for each x => I expect a value which I want to append to globalBuffer.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, so for each x you want a single proportion? If, so then I think either Ashalynd's or my approach (which are pretty much the same modulo some small details) will work fine. You just need to do a `joined.collect` to obtain a local collection, assuming that's what you ultimately want.

Comment: @JasonLenderman so this is what I did after I used your method `val runningAvg = positiveCount.toDouble/count`
`globalBuffer += runningAvg`

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, forget about `globalBuffer`. See my answer on why this won't work. The `RDD` `joined` created by Ashalynd's or my code will contain all the proportions you want. If you want it in a local `Array` then just use val `localJoined = joined.collect`. If you need it in a `List` then use `val localJoined = joined.collect.toList`.

Comment: Or you can add .collect.toList right to the definition of joined if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Transformations of `RDDs` are not going to modify `globalBuffer`. *Copies* of `globalBuffer` are made and sent out to each of the workers, but any modifications to these copies on the workers will never modify the `globalBuffer` that exists on the driver (the one you have defined outside the `map` on the `RDD`.) Here's what I do (with a few additional modifications):

```
val joined = data1.cogroup(data2) map { x =>
  val iterA = x._2._1
  val iterB = x._2._2
  var count, positiveCount = 0
  val tempList = ListBuffer[(Int, Double)]()
  for (tupleB <- iterB) {
    tempList.clear
    for(tupleA <- iterA) {
      val tValue = someFunctionReturnDouble(tupleB._2, tupleA._2)
      tempList += ((tupleA._1, tValue))
    }
    val sortList = tempList.sortWith(_._2 > _._2).iterator.take(20)
    if (sortList.exists(_._1 == tupleB._1)) positiveCount += 1
    count += 1
  }
  positiveCount.toDouble/count
}
```

At this point you can obtain of local copy of the proportions by using `joined.collect`.

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, see my comment before the code -- a transformation on an `RDD` *cannot* modify the state of any object on the driver (unless you're using `Accumulators/Accumalables`, which you're not... and I don't advise in this situation.)

Comment: @Null-Hypothesis, in case you are not aware (please forgive me if you are), in Scala the last value evaluated is what is return by a function. So the above function (which is passed into the `map` method of `RDD`) will map each `x` to `positiveCount.toDouble/count`. The result of the `map` method applied to this function will be an `RDD` containing  these proportions.